# Error Converting data type Varchar to float in SQL

Tags: sql

I have been trying to extract the values from an table using the below query but getting the Error

Having a column where having the datatype as varchar but i need to extract the values which is greater than 500% in col3

Sample Data

```
Col1  Col2       Col3
1     15066052   555.5%
2     15066032   25.0
3     15066052   500.8%
4     15066052   450.5
5     15066041   500%


Select *
from Table1 where ([Col2]='15066052'AND Cast(Replace(LTRIM(RTRIM([Col3)) , '%','') as numeric(19,4)) > 500)
```

Error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Execute `select table1.*, Replace(LTRIM(RTRIM([Col3)) , '%','') from Table1`. Does the output make sense?

Comment: mysql and sql server are two different database products.

Comment: @jarlh - When trying to execute the Error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '79.75' to data type int."

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to tag correctly.

Comment: My query involved no cast... It's meant to show you what you try to cast.

Comment: The expression is in the `WHERE` though, @jarlh , and it compares to an `int`, so there is implicit conversion.

Comment: The *real* problem here, @Manz , is your design; you are storing numerical data in a string based data type. The *real* solution is to fix your design.

Comment: @Larnu I am suppose to extract the value as a string only in the environment where the data is being used, only condition i have to check is to get the values more than 500 from column 3

Comment: So why not store your percentage values as a numeric. `'500%'` should therefore be `5`; then (again) you can store your numerical data as a numerical data type and you have no conversion errors..

Comment: @Larnu, I know, but you can't see what happens in the WHERE clause. That's why I asked OP to move the expression to be casted to the SELECT clause. Classic problem solving trick.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL -https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vm5neG3srXt6SbWvvST5x/0

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(col3)) , '%','') AS newCol
    FROM Table1  
    ) AS innertable 
WHERE newCol > 500;
```

SQL Server 2019 - adapted from Larnu's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7196e7fb2f1812fd0793fd0cbfd1e446)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(col3)) , '%','') AS newCol
    FROM Table1  
    ) as innertable
WHERE CAST(newCol AS numeric(19,4)) > 500;
```

Comment: This is going to result in the error the OP has in the comments: *"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '{Value}' to data type int."*

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vm5neG3srXt6SbWvvST5x/0

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding what the  OP actually needs I thought this would suffice.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7196e7fb2f1812fd0793fd0cbfd1e446). Unfortunately the OP has failed to tell us what RDBMS they are *really* using still, but the fact that they got the error, and you don't on MySQL, suggests that they are using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: My apologies, I did not realize OP was using SQL Server.

Comment: They don't confirm they are, however, it can be safely inferred from the comments, based on the verbatim quoted error in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968142/error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-float-in-sql/71968830?noredirect=1#comment127169696_71968142). That isn't your fault, but the solution you proposed was suggested in the comments, and the error generated.